# Ancestry - show categories where at least one category in the tree has a product

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ancestry, globalize

I use ancestry and globalize gems for my categories and any category can have products associated with it.

What I want to do, is to show the whole tree of categories (in specific language, if exists), where at least one category in that tree contains a product (not only categories where the products are).

So far I have the following code, which does almost what I need, but it just filters categories where the products are, but I need to get the whole tree (from root to bottom).

```
Category.includes(:translations, category_maps: [:products]).where(category_translations: {:locale => I18n.locale.to_s} ).group("categories.id, category_maps.id, category_translations.id, products.id").having("count(products.id) > ?",0).arrange_serializable(:order => 'category_translations.name')
```

Any idea how to achieve this? 
Thank you, Miroslav

## Solution

I finally found a way how to do it from other side. In my view where are iterate the root categories, before I render the whole categories tree, I verify that at least one category in the tree contains a product and then render the categories, otherwise not.

```
<% if Category.find(root['id']).subtree.joins(:products).group("categories.id").having("count(products.id) > ?",0).length > 0 %>
```

Comment: A personal recommendation; you'll be much better using `acts_as_tree`

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way how to do it from other side. In my view where are iterate the root categories, before I render the whole categories tree, I verify that at least one category in the tree contains a product and then render the categories, otherwise not.

```
<% if Category.find(root['id']).subtree.joins(:products).group("categories.id").having("count(products.id) > ?",0).length > 0 %>
```